# How to replace the day in a date with another date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace the day in my if statement for my date but I keep getting this output for my year.
05/15/5 besides 05/15/2020  . Code is below:

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
date = today_date.date()
formatted_date = datetime.date.strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")

mmonth = date.month
myear = date.year
mdate = date.day

if mdate < 7:
    m0weekend = formatted_date.replace(str(myear),str(mmonth),1)
else:
    m0weekend = formatted_date.replace(str(myear),str(mmonth),15)
```

Answer (score 7):

it's easier to replace the day before converting to a string:
`date = date.replace(day=1)`

or, in your case:

```
if mdate < 7:
    m0weekend = date.replace(day=1)
else:
    m0weekend = date.replace(day=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

formatted_date is actually a string. 
You are using the [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method not the [datetime.date.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) method.

```
import datetime

today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
pre_formatted_date = today_date.date()


mmonth = pre_formatted_date.month
myear = pre_formatted_date.year
mdate = pre_formatted_date.day

if mdate < 7:
    pre_formatted_date = pre_formatted_date.replace(day=1)
else:
    pre_formatted_date = pre_formatted_date.replace(day=15)

print(pre_formatted_date)
formatted_date = pre_formatted_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(formatted_date)
```

Which has the following output:

```
2020-05-15
05/15/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get today `datetime.date` directly from `datetime` rather than creating `datetime.datetime` and converting to date. After you have today you might create needed `datetime.date` and turn it into `str`, i.e.:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
date = datetime.date(today.year, today.month, 1 if today.day < 7 else 15)
formatted_date = datetime.date.strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
print(formatted_date)  # 05/15/2020
```